# Replace Last 2 Digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a way to search through column "B" and replace the last two digits of values listed.

For example,

I'd like to have,

`502040155 replaced to 5020400,`

`403041055 to 4030400,`

`603054055 to 6040500,`

etc.

I'm assuming a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` formula is needed? `VBA` or formula works fine.a

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your last example was a typo. Try,

```
=FLOOR(A2/100, 100)
```

[image]